# Blazor sub app 404 error after upgrade to Preview 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor Preview 5 (.Net Core Hosted), I have successfully configured the app as a sub app on the Asp.net Core site using:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

app.Map("/superadmin", child => { 
child.UseBlazor<BlazorCoreHosted.SuperAdmin.Startup>(); });
```

I am now trying to upgrade to Preview 6, but when the app loads I get a 404 error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

THe URL being looked for is - http://localhost:52112/superadmin/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js

I have tried the instructions at the following link, and variations of the same, but can't get past the error.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/

Can anyone advise how to get past this error?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your application still has references to .NET Core Preview 5, since `UseBlazor` is gone now.

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
app.Map("/superadmin", child =>
{
    child.UseRouting();
    child.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
    });
    child.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();
});
app.Map("/superadmin2", child =>
{
    child.UseRouting();
    child.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client2.Startup>("index.html");
    });
    child.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client2.Startup>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me a big step forward

It works fine for 1 app, but if I repeat for a second app I get a message "AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. "

If I leave out "endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Manager.Startup>("index.html");" for the second app the site loads but hangs, with an error saying it can't fing the blazor.webassembly.js for app 2 in the path to app 1

Is there a way to get around this? In the Preview 5 version I had 3 sub apps working as expected

Comment: You should add `child.UseRouting()` for each sub route. I update answer with required changes