# How to use both Blazor client and server in same web

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

I'm learning about the `Blazor`, and see benefit of 2 types `client-side` and `server-side`.

I want to use both on the same web e.g. one path is a `client-side` `WebAssembly` app, another path is a `server-side` that run code in server.

I have seen `Blazor Full-Stack` template (not quite understand) but it missing from latest templates package. Did they remove it on purpose?
(only 2 left `Blazor Server App` and  `Blazor WebAssembly App`)

I download templates from this command.

`dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19465.2`

Can `client-side` and `server-side` work together?

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58118874/child-blazor-app-on-blazor-server-side-app?noredirect=1#comment102628900_58118874 ?

Comment: No. You have to choose one or the other. Either way it's still Blazor, so there's nothing to signal which one would be used where. The difference lies in the underlying implementations (SignalR vs. Web Assembly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not officially supported or build, but, it is in theory possible. However, it is something they are looking into.

Source (**start watching from 28:35**): https://youtu.be/qF6ixMjCzHA?t=1715

Comment: can you add information from video to the answer, please?

Comment: Was there any development in this direction?

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible in .NET 8 using the new Blazor render modes. You can now setup the render location (i.e. Blazor Server or Blazor Client/WebAssembly) independently for every page and every components, simply by using the following directives:

For Blazor Server:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

For Blazor WebAssembly:

```
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
```

And it's even possible to have a page/component that renders in the server for the very first load, then renders in client/WebAssembly for all the next loads, so the user is not slowed down by the WebAssembly package loading during the first load, using:

```
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
```

For more info, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: this is not simply true. dont mislead with this answer. there are several rules and restrictions for that.