# Can I use both Blazor client-side and server-side in the same project, and more importantly can i use it in the same page?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I know that there is the same question here somewhere that has been answered and i have heard people from the ndc conferences that say that "there is nothing stopping you from doing that" and there "should be a support for that" but i didn't get the answer to my second question and i haven't managed to get an implementation somewhere about both.

The second part of my question is that can i run both at the same time in a page. This might be useful because i can use the server side to get the data from my database and then use the client side to render the page and other components that do not pose a security risk if they are compiled in the clients browser.

Can somebody help me out, and if you can link me projects that somebody has tested or published that would be very helpful.

PS: I'm sorry if i made grammatical errors, i hope i was clear enough for you guys to understand my questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use both Blazor client and server in same web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131674/how-to-use-both-blazor-client-and-server-in-same-web)

Answer (score 2):

No, currently not.
However this is one feature the Blazor team is considering for the future.
However you can just use a common ASP.NET Core backend in the same solution to get the data from database and a shared project for your models.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Ignoring client side routing, I don't see why you couldn't render two separate components that use a different hosting model.

Comment: I think this is correct but a link (to a GitHub issue or a Blog) would strengthen this answer.

Comment: while searching for a source i found your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131674/how-to-use-both-blazor-client-and-server-in-same-web but at least they have some sauce.

Comment: I have 3 projects hosted, serverside and another with shared code (pages, controls, ... ) In my opinion is better than a single project with both behaviors.